# Portable class library design

Tags: c#, interface, cross-platform

I have a portable class library that, for example, exposes this interface method:

```cs
public interface IPortablePainter
{
    void PaintTheSky(PortableColor color);
}
```

Then, I need to define some platform-specific implementation, (totally invented, just for example):

Android implementation:

```
public class AndroidPainter : IPortablePainter
{
    public void PaintTheSky(PortableColor color)
    {
        AndroidFrameworkColor convertedColor = ToColor(color);
        // DrawSky needs an AndroidFrameworkColor, not a PortableColor
        AndroidFrameworkPainter.DrawSky(convertedColor);
    }
}

public static AndroidFrameworkColor ToColor(PortableColor color)
{
    return new AndroidFrameworkColor()
    {
        A = color.A,
        R = color.R,
        G = color.G,
        B = color.B
    };
}
```

iOS implementation:

```
public class iOSPainter : IPortablePainter
{
    public void PaintTheSky(PortableColor color)
    {
        iOSFrameworkColor convertedColor = ToColor(color);
        // DrawSky needs an iOSFrameworkColor, not a PortableColor
        iOSFrameworkPainter.DrawSky(convertedColor);
    }
}

public static iOSFrameworkColor ToColor(PortableColor color)
{
    return new iOSFrameworkColor()
    {
        AlphaChannel = color.A,
        RedChannel = color.R,
        GreenChannel = color.G,
        BlueChannel = color.B
    };
}
```

Note that I don't own `AndroidFrameworkColor` and `iOSFrameworkColor`, nor `AndroidFrameworkPainter` and `iOSFrameworkPainter`, I can't touch that classes' definition, consider them as built-in on the platform base framework.

The questions are:

- Is defining a converter function, in this situation, the best choice in terms of performance? I would like to define an implicit operator, but I can't because I don't own framework specific classes. Also, I don't feel as "clear" writing `ToColor` everytime, since I'll have to call it a lot.
- What are the other patterns or design strategies to define an abstract/interface method that could encapsulate a pre-existing class method I don't own?

Comment: If there is only a limited set of colours to be used, then you can cache them. I don't see an easy way to simplify the code further, as you are doing cross platform and there is a price to pay.

Comment: Adding widening and narrowing operators to your PortableColor class seems like a good place to start.